# How do you transcribe these sounds you make in IPA?

Tags: ipa

Uvular ejective fricative χʼ? I don’t know. It seems not.

- https://youtu.be/3u65Dk1bqWg?t=584
- https://youtu.be/d3oBs5TljNE?t=8193
- https://youtu.be/B2FkJVj2hj4?t=39
- https://youtu.be/quF-CDV3K68?t=223
- https://youtu.be/LxdoJjN7_p8?t=25

Answer (score 3):

They all sound different, but generally they sound somewhere between [x] and [χ] possibly with added diacritics. Nothing sounded ejective (using Tigrinya, which has /χ'/, as my standard). There is no accepted diacritic for notating trilling, but I would notate the second example (which was the one with decent sound quality) as [χ̌]. If you had a consistent set of well-recorded examples of that kind, you could submit them to acoustic analysis, but just to point to a payoff, intervocalic /χ/ in Tigrinya often sounds somewhat voiced, because there is soft tissue trilling (of the pharyngeal walls) as air passes through the narrow fricative passage. Thus you can actually count the flappings of tissue, which allow you to class the sound as a "trill".

Comment: How about [the _voiceless uvular trill_ ʀ̥](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_uvular_trill)? Do you think any of the samples are making this sound?